# remove file's end and the begigng using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

i have a folder contains  pdf files starting with paracel_ and end with _manifest

for example :
paracel_123_manifest

i use this command to remove the "*manifest" from the file but i dont konw how to remove the "paracel*" from the satart of the file

$dir = "C:\temp"
$phrase = "_manifest"

$length=$phrase.Length

Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse| Where-Object { $*.Name -like "*$phrase*" } | Rename-Item -NewName { $*.name.substring(0,$*.BaseName.length-$length)+$*.Extension}# -WhatIf -verbose

thanks in advance!!
hope someone can assist
A

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = "C:\temp" 
$phrase = "_manifest"
    
Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter "paracel_*$phrase*.pdf" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name.Replace("_manifest","")).Replace("paracel_","") -WhatIf -verbose
}
```

You were on the right path. I just changed the filter and put parsed the items in a foreach loop.

Comment: Forgot to add the replacing of paracel_ but edited the answer!